# Second order equation in $Z_n$

Tags: ring-theory

Find $n \ge 2, n \in N  $ such that the equation $ x^2-\hat{3}x+\hat{5}=\hat{0}$ has only one solution in the ring $(Z_n,+,\cdot)$.

[Attempt]
$ x^2-\hat{3}x+\hat{5}=\hat{0}$ $\iff$ there is some $k \in Z$ such that $ x^2-3x+5=kn$. The solutions to this equation are $$ x_{1,2}=\frac{3 \pm \sqrt{4kn-11}}{2} $$
Now because $0\le x_{1,2}\le n-1, \ k $ must be $\gt 0$.
If $k=1$ then $n\ge 3$. If $n=3$ then the equation has two solutions , false. If $n\ge4$ then
$\sqrt{4n-11} \ge \sqrt{5} \ $ and $\dfrac{3-\sqrt{4n-11}}{2} \ $ is not a natural number, so the only solution that remains would be $\dfrac{3+\sqrt{4n-11}}{2} \ $.This is a natural number only if $d=\sqrt{4n-11}$ is odd. So $d$ is odd and let's note $ d=2t+1$, then: $$\dfrac{3+\sqrt{4n-11}}{2}  = \dfrac{3+d}{2} =\dfrac{3+2t+1}{2}=t+2 $$
and $ \ d=\sqrt{4n-11} \iff n=\frac{d^2-11}{4}  \ $  for $d \ge 3$ which works. But I don't know how to solve for $k \ge 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n$ even, the congruence $x^2-3x+5\equiv 0 \pmod n$ implies $x^2-3x+5\equiv 0 \pmod 2$ which has no solution.

For $n$ odd, $2$ is invertible, so the equation is equivalent to $(2n-3)^2\equiv -11 \pmod n$.

If $-11$ is not a square modulo $n$ there is no solution.

If $-11\equiv u^2\pmod n$ for some $u$ then $\frac{3+u}{2}$ and $\frac{3-u}{2}$ are solutions of the equation. If they are different we have more than one solution.

If $\frac{3+u}{2}=\frac{3-u}{2}$ then $u=0$. This means $-11 \equiv u^2 \equiv  0 \pmod n$, so $$n=11$$